# How to sort 13 enormous polynomials, each having terms with 5 variables ($1>h_0>h_1>h_2>h_3>h_4$)?

Tags: polynomials

Both algebraically or with software (numerically/computationally, for example) is acceptable. Here is a how one of the polynomials looks like ($L<1$ is a constant).

I have attached a text file with all the 13 polynomials that I need to sort in ascending order - more precisely, I have a target order I need to achieve, so I need to define the ranges of the variables $h_0$ - $h_4$ where that order would be valid. Here is one representative polynomial sample:

$$
7 h_0 h_1^2 h_2^2 h_3 L^3 + 
29 h_0 h_1^2 h_2^2 h_3 h_4^2 L^4 + 
3 h_0 h_2^2 h_4 L^2 + 
5 h_0 h_2^2 h_4^3 L^3 + 
\ldots
$$

Each polynomial has approximately 200 terms(!).

Comment: I don't understand completely. Are $h_i$ variables, or are they numbers with the ordering that you present in the title? If they are variables what are the range for each one? And, if that's the case they might be larger in some regions and smaller in others.

Comment: h_i are variables. They are involved in terms that form 13 polynomials. Each of the 13 polynomials represent physical magnitudes that I know how they should be sorted (obtained as experimental evidence), so I need to find variables' regions where that particular polynomial sorting order is valid. One known condition (constraint) for the variables is that 1>h0>h1>h2>h3>h4.

Comment: Is your condition a necessary one but not sufficient one then?

Comment: What you're describing (set given by polynomial inequality constraints) is usually called a [semialgebraic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set), and it's usually a very difficult problem, in general, when the polynomials are large. Perhaps randomization or cylindrical algebraic decomposition might work?

Comment: Yes, nicoguaro, that one condition is necessary, but I need to find additional, or to prove that one is sufficient.

Comment: Ups, I missed an important part in the condition - at the lower part it is limited by zero: 1>h0>h1>h2>h3>h4 >0. Hi Kirill, thanks for the suggestion - I am trying to understand (Wikipedia) what are and if/how can I use randomization or cylindrical algebraic decomposition... as not being a mathematician my self, it's a challenge, but I'll give my best. :)

Comment: I was thinking to try a numerical method (to calculate the values of these 13 polynomials) for different sets (combinations...  a lot of them) of h0-h4 values, so I could possibly find the ranges. My (additional) problem there would be to find the necessary precision that I should use, so I won't miss any distinct range (since the real numbers set is dense).

Comment: Update: I tried Wolfram Mathematica's cylindrical decomposition - it worked, but the answer I got looks more complicated than the question I asked... :( 
I'll try with the numerical method I mentioned above... however, it looks like it will take a very long time to calculate by using a regular personal computer, so if someone has another idea, it would be quite appreciated. 
Again, thank you all for your advises.

Comment: @TPank I would say there isn't enough information in the question to make it easy to help. If Mathematica's CAD works for you, that's great, it's probably more than one can usually hope for with questions of this type.